How to playback an M3U8 Video from Cache in iOS?
I am dealing with an M3U8 video file where I'm trying to play it after  storing such remote videos in my SwiftUI app.
The main approach I found so far is the accepted answer in this thread: Is it possible to cache Videos? IOS - Swift
Problem: 
However, when I try to implement it, the M3U8 video does not load.
If I was to play directly from the videoURL, then there would be no issues and the video plays. But I would also like to play it from the cache.
VideoPlayer(player: player)
    .onAppear {
        CacheManager.shared.getFileWith(stringUrl: videoURL) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let url):
                self.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                self.player?.play()
            case .failure:
                print("Error")
            }
        }
    }

For context, printing the URL from CacheManager gives file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2F12CCE9-1D0C-447B-9B96-9EC6F6BE1413/Library/Caches/filename  (where filename is the actual filename).
And this is what the video player looks like when running the app.

So is there an issue with my implementation of the code? Is the accepted answer from the old thread actually invalid/outdated and no longer works with current iOS versions? Does anyone have an alternative method for caching videos?

Does this 10 second example MP4 file work from your cache? With that file... Does AVPlayer load the https:// version but not the file:/// path version, or both work ok?

PS: You need to mention your video format or even the file extension. It can give us a clue about the issue (eg: saying "My video URL is a Youtube link" tells us at once why this will not work). Provide a testable video link to avoid guesses... There could be a lot of things going on,,, (1) You downloaded an encrypted video? (2) Your video is not a video (eg: maybe it's actually an .m3u8 playlist file)? (3) For security reasons, it doesn't like that file:/// in your path, unless you maybe instead use the file picker API (where a user selected file is usually allowed to play).

@VC.One Yes you're right, I was actually just beginning to suspect that might be the issue and testing with the video you provided helped confirm that. This is because the API I am using is returning the videos in a .m3u8 format even though they are only single videos and not playlists. Do you know how I can handle this case then?

Try to check the file with MediaInfo Online. What does it say about its format? Anyways, If it's a single file then you can try renaming it. Try renaming it into filename.mp4 instead of filename.m3u8 then test playing with AVPlayer... Also the file is big enough to be a video, correct?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/offline_playback_and_storage/using_avfoundation_to_play_and_persist_http_live_streams

@VC.One Sorry that was phrased poorly, it is a m3u8 file that describes a playlist, but it's always a playlist of just one video. I'm currently looking into how I can get that video and convert it to a MP4 easily for caching locally, but just changing the filename doesn't work.

Do you see (a) #EXT-X-STREAM-INF or you see (b) #EXTINF: showing in the text of m3u8?

@VC.One So the file directly fetched from API has #EXT-X-STREAM-INF and the line afterwards links another m3u8 file. Going to that file, it has #EXTINF and the line after links the .ts file

@fadipon Okay with that information I can write an Answer. Basically, the second m3u8 (listing TS file) and also its related TS file are the two things you must download . Then put both files in a sub-folder on your cache. PS: I suspect that since this only one TS file is representing the whole video then maybe it's enough to just try playing the TS file alone with AVPlayer?

@VC.One Unfortunately AVPlayer cannot play TS files, it has to be encoded in m3u8 first. This is why I'm not sure if caching the files is enough unless it is possible to create a m3u8 file that encodes and points to a TS file that is stored locally (or something else that lets the TS file be readable by AVPlayer)

@fadipon Yes caching the files is enough. Is it "possible to create an m3u8 file that encodes.."? Yes, but I wanted to avoid doing that part by first testing the TS file itself. PS: Sorry about these crazy response times... Let me just write you a full Answer that might help you better.

I ended up mainly implementing the approach in: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/offline_playback_and_storage/using_avfoundation_to_play_and_persist_http_live_streams.
The sample code demonstrated a method for downloading HLS content however the videos were being saved in a public folder users could access from Settings, as well as using UserDefaults to store the locations, which were both features I did not want as I wanted to implement a cache that downloads videos when they load to remove later.
So I modified and simplified the code as such:
class Asset {
    var urlAsset: AVURLAsset
    var name: String
    
    init(urlAsset: AVURLAsset, name: String) {
        self.urlAsset = urlAsset
        self.name = name
    }
}

class AssetPersistenceManager: NSObject {
    static let shared = AssetPersistenceManager()
    private var assetDownloadURLSession: AVAssetDownloadURLSession!
    private var activeDownloadsMap = [AVAssetDownloadTask: Asset]()
    private var willDownloadToUrlMap = [AVAssetDownloadTask: URL]()
    
    private let fileManager = FileManager.default
    
    override private init() {
        super.init()

        // Create the configuration for the AVAssetDownloadURLSession.
        let backgroundConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "AAPL-Identifier")

        // Create the AVAssetDownloadURLSession using the configuration.
        assetDownloadURLSession = AVAssetDownloadURLSession(configuration: backgroundConfiguration,
                                                            assetDownloadDelegate: self,
                                                            delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    }
    
    func downloadStream(for asset: Asset) async {
        guard let task = assetDownloadURLSession.makeAssetDownloadTask(
            asset: asset.urlAsset,
            assetTitle: asset.urlAsset.url.lastPathComponent,
            assetArtworkData: nil,
            options: [AVAssetDownloadTaskMinimumRequiredMediaBitrateKey: 265_000]
        ) else { return }
        
        activeDownloadsMap[task] = asset
        
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func localAssetForStream(withName name: String) -> AVURLAsset? {
        let documentsUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
        let localFileLocation = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(name)
        guard !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: localFileLocation.path)  else {
            return AVURLAsset(url: localFileLocation)
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
    func cleanCache() {
        do {
            let documentsUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
            let contents = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
            for file in contents {
                do {
                    try fileManager.removeItem(at: file)
                }
                catch {
                    print("An error occured trying to delete the contents on disk for: \(file).")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed to clean cache.")
        }
    }
}

extension AssetPersistenceManager: AVAssetDownloadDelegate {

    /// Tells the delegate that the task finished transferring data.
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        guard let task = task as? AVAssetDownloadTask,
            let asset = activeDownloadsMap.removeValue(forKey: task) else { return }

        guard let downloadURL = willDownloadToUrlMap.removeValue(forKey: task) else { return }

        if let error = error as NSError? {
            switch (error.domain, error.code) {
            case (NSURLErrorDomain, NSURLErrorCancelled):
                /*
                 This task was canceled, you should perform cleanup using the
                 URL saved from AVAssetDownloadDelegate.urlSession(_:assetDownloadTask:didFinishDownloadingTo:).
                 */
                guard let localFileLocation = localAssetForStream(withName: asset.name)?.url else { return }

                do {
                    try fileManager.removeItem(at: localFileLocation)
                } catch {
                    print("An error occured trying to delete the contents on disk for \(asset.name): \(error)")
                }

            case (NSURLErrorDomain, NSURLErrorUnknown):
                fatalError("Downloading HLS streams is not supported in the simulator.")

            default:
                fatalError("An unexpected error occured \(error.domain)")
            }
        } else {
            do {
                let documentsUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
                let newURL = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(asset.name)
                try fileManager.moveItem(at: downloadURL, to: newURL)
            } catch {
                print("Failed to move downloaded file to temp directory.")
            }
        }
    }

    /// Method called when the an aggregate download task determines the location this asset will be downloaded to.
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        willDownloadToUrlMap[assetDownloadTask] = location
    }
}

Most notably, I changed the delegate for handling the completion of the download to move the file to a /tmp directory afterwards so it no longer appears in Settings. This now lets me asynchronously download HTTP Streams and cache them in a temporary directory for later fetching.

To make the playback work, you can try these steps:
(1) Download both the .m3u8 and the related .ts file(s) as listed within the M3U8 file.
(2) Inside the M3U8, change the text of the path by removing any sub-folders. 
eg: if your M3U8 path is: /cdn_url/video720/filename.ts just remove the /cdn_url/video720/ text.
Then your M3U8 should look something like this (where only its own file path is changed):
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:30
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXTINF:30.0,
filename.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST

It is a good idea also to rename both the M3U8 and TS with a matching file "name" to identify playlist videos.
eg: Make it as Batman_ep_01.m3u8 and Batman_ep_01.ts
(3) Save and test in AVPlayer.
What about multiple TS files in one M3U8?
It works the same as Step (2) but you simply put the M3U8 and its related TS files into a unique sub-folder. Something like below where the m3u8 and ts files are stored.
eg: /Library/Caches/some_Show_multi/

Thanks for all the help, your feedback really helped me better understand the problem and what I should be trying to do to solve it. I ended up going with another approach I was working on that ended up working but I do appreciate it
